# Javascript Prohibit access to a page that is directly typed in the browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser

Is it possible to Prohibit access to a page that is directly typed in the browser but without prohibiting it if the url comes from an iframe ?

Comment: Possibly, maybe using the referer header will catch half of the cases. But no, you should not do that, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hm ok then the best thing to do is play with the url by putting an encrypted md5 string generated since the date as /?key=<?=md5 ("20181001-JhGf54");?>&date=20181001 and NodeJS server side must get the date and key and generated a md5 to check if it is equal from the NodeJS server?
Do you have to do that better with the date or the same time?

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do. You want to restrict access to a certain page, but by what? A user authentication? Do you really care whether the page is embedded in an iframe or not?

Answer (score 1):

**Any** client-side check you do can be bypassed. For a robust mechanism, you'll need to involve a server: Have clicking on the link send a message to the server with a browser signature (including IP), which you record with the date/time. When the protected page is requested, check the browser signature in the request and ensure it matches a signature received within an acceptable time prior to the request. This can also be bypassed, just a bit less easily.

In terms of client-side-only mechanisms (which, again, are easily bypassed):

- You'll probably get people pointing you at [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer), but it's **extremely** easy to spoof and I wouldn't rely on it.
- The only other way I can think of is if both pages are in the same origin. If so, when the user clicks the link in the iframe, you can set a value in `localStorage`:

  ```
  // (In a click handler on the link)
  localStorage.setItem("clicktime", Date.now());
  ```

  ...and in the page:

  ```
  var MAX_DURATION = 500; // milliseconds
  var clicktime = localStorage.getItem("clicktime");
  if (!clicktime || isNaN(clicktime) || Date.now() - MAX_DURATION > 500) {
      // Disallow access by (for instance) redirecting or similar
  }
  ```

...but again, client-side mechanisms are easily bypassed.